# Portfolio Optimization - Pull individual Stock

Tags: python, portfolio

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import time
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import requests

# dummy function to create url link
def make_url(ticker_symbol, unix_start, unix_end, daily):
    """
    This function creates a url link for query
    
    Argument:
    ticker_symbol -- the symbol of the stock
    unix_start    -- start time
    unix_end      -- end time
    daily         -- True to fetch daily stock price
                     False to fetch monthly stock price
    
    Returns:
    link -- url link
    """
        
    if daily:
        link = 'https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ticker_symbol +'/history?period1='+str(unix_start)+'&period2='+str(unix_end)+'&filter=history&interval=1d&frequency=1d'
    else:
        link ='https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/' + ticker_symbol +'/history?period1='+str(unix_start)+'&period2='+str(unix_end)+'&filter=history&interval=1mo&frequency=1mo'
    return link

def pull_historical_data(ticker_symbol, output_path, unix_start, unix_end, daily, is_save):
    import requests, re, json
    """
    This function pull individual stock
    
    Argument:
    ticker_symbol -- the symbol of the stock
    output_path   -- full path to folder that stores the data
    unix_start    -- start time
    unix_end      -- end time
    daily         -- True to fetch daily stock price
                     False to fetch monthly stock price
    is_save       -- True to save the data 
    
    Returns:
    df -- dataframe to hold the stock data
    """

    r = requests.get(make_url(ticker_symbol, unix_start, unix_end, daily))
    ptrn = r'root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);'
    

    tmpTxt = re.search(ptrn, r.text, re.DOTALL)
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    if tmpTxt is not None:
        txt = tmpTxt.group(1)
        jsn = json.loads(txt)
        
        ### START CODE HERE

        
        ### END CODE HERE
        
        if is_save:     
            df.to_csv(make_filename(ticker_symbol, output_path)) 
    
    return df
```

I was asked to fill an incomplete function to pull individual stocks. I was wondering what kind of text pattern that   `ptrn = r'root\.App\.main = (.*?);\n}\(this\)\);'`  looks for in the second function. And I was also wondering how to fill out the blank in the second function.

Comment: That regex will match something like `root.App.main = something;
}(this));`. A regex tester like regex101 is good for this type of stuff.

Comment: What exactly do you want the blank section in the second function to do?